# Migration of .NET v4.6.2 to .NET CORE 3.1 - OWIN Authentication

Tags: .net, authentication, .net-core, owin, itfoxtec-identity-saml2

My apologies for the non-descriptive short description above.

Context:
We have a range of projects developed using .NET v4.6.2. They use OWIN to authenticate the user. We use Ping SSO. Owin makes sure to create the cookie when the user is authenticated. With this, user is not sent to login IDP when cookie is available though user moves from one application to another.

Now,  We are upgrading the applications one by one to .NET Core 3.1.  Problem is we have used ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2 for SSO login. Now, newly developed application is not able to read OWIN cookie generated in old application.

Is there any way out :(

Answer (score 0):

It is insecure to use the same cookie across applications and domains, and it is not supported in .NET Core for security reasons.

You should redirect the user to your IdP (Ping SSO) from each application on each login request. And let the IdP hold the identity cookie on one domain.